# Continue Shopping URI

Tags: php, opencart

In my cart I have it so when you add a product you get taken to the shopping cart and the client wishes the user to click continue shopping and be taken back to the added items category for further shopping.  How could I do this?

The category URI segment is 1 after the domain.

Comment: It's unclear what version of opencart you are using, and the method it employs changes depending on the version. What version are you running this code on?

Comment: Wow, OK well you should upgrade to 1.4.9 at the very least. I realise that's not always possible, but for security I'd highly recommend it. Will put a possible solution in an answer below

Comment: @JayGilford I was meaning v1.5.1.3.  Will try your answer after I fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248251/internet-explorer-jquery-redirect

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the 1.5.x version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `catalog/controller/product/category.php`

Find `if ($category_info) {` on approx line 75

On a new line after it put

```
$tmp = $this->request->get;
unset($tmp['route']);
$this->session->data['continue_redirect'] = $this->url->link('product/category', http_build_query($tmp));
```

That code basically sets the url to the current page url if the category is a valid category into a session variable

Open `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php`

Find `$this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');` around line 285

After that line, put

```
if(!empty($this->session->data['continue_redirect'])) {
    $this->data['continue'] = $this->session->data['continue_redirect'];
    unset($this->session->data['continue_redirect']);
}
```

This checks for the continue_redirect session variable we set in the category controller, and if it's set assigns it to the continue URL, then unsets it so that it doesn't retain that category information. If you want it to, delete the line

```
unset($this->session->data['continue_redirect']);
```

Please note that this has not been tested, but should work in theory, as I don't have a 1.3.x installation

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to just add a GET parameter to the "Add to Cart" link which contains the path to the item's category. Something like `example.com/shopping_cart.php?item=bunny_slippers&item_category=/categories/footwear/` would do. I'm not sure what your application structure is like, but you could either do this by setting a `$category` variable  for each category page and then inserting that variable into the GET parameter, or you could grab the path info using PHP's SERVER superglobal.

Then, on the shopping cart page, you can simply insert the `$_GET['item_category']` variable into your "Continue Shopping" link. Of course you'd have to do so basic sanitation on the parameter first to make sure it didn't have any malicious code in it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jay Gilfords answer above - I have just tried this and found another instance of

```
$this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
```

about line 258. I also needed to put the code after that or the redirect only worked if the basket was empty.

Answer (score 0):

you could set a cookie on the client that listed their last browsing category before adding to the cart, or you could set it in their user session.

Comment: This has been done by using the user session but if you read my last comment on this post I cannot seem to find the related code :) http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=37372