# Internet Explorer jQuery Redirect

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, opencart

I am currently working on http://thetradinghouse.co.nz and I have an issue when accessing the cart the process that is taken is.

- Select Category.
- Select a product and open the products page.
- Click add to cart.
- The product adds to the cart but the page redirects to the category page with the uri `http://www.thetradinghouse.co.nz/sporting-goods/index.php?route=checkout/cart`

The above step should just load `http://www.thetradinghouse.co.nz/index.php?route=checkout/cart` Like it does in Chrome and Firefox

I am using the following [SEO Module](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/download/info&order_id=44368) and have been in contact with the developer whom I have stumped with this issue.

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/1389706) to my product.tpl and common.js as it was too big to implement here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best fix for this is to do the following

Open `/catalog/view/javascript/common.js`

Find the `addToCart` function in that file, and then find the first instance of

```
window.location.href = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
```

after it. Change that line to

```
window.location.href = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
```

Save, and upload to your server via FTP if necessary

Comment: Found the issue Jay product.tpl line 354 changed to the above.

Comment: Ah I see. By the looks of it your theme is using it's own functions rather than the common.js file

Answer (score 0):

I looks like IE is interpreting your redirect poorly. I'd try swapping

121:    `window.location.href = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';`

with an absolute url:

`window.location.href = 'http://www.thetradinghouse.co.nz/index.php?route=checkout/cart'`