# jquery fade out and redirect not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a website on which I have the following script intended to handle all links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").css("display","none");
$("body").fadeIn(2000);
$("a").click(function(event){event.preventDefault();
linkLocation=this.href;
if(!linkLocation.contains("#")){$("body").fadeOut(1000,redirectPage);
}});

function redirectPage(){
window.location=linkLocation;}})
```

What it should do is, when a link is clicked to fade out and then to fade back in.

The issue I am facing is that in IE, links simply do not work.

Is it possible to edit my code in order for it to work?

If not, is there a way I can use a fallback code during this issue?

This issue is not present in chrome and I am using the latest IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check if your url contains the substring that you want to check with using *indexOf()* method. If it contains that character/substring then it'll return any **0** or **positive value**. Else it'll return **-1** .

*Try this way :*

**HTML :**

```
<a href="www.google.com">ToogleFade</a>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    $("a").on("click", function(e){
        linkLocation = $(this).attr("href");
        e.preventDefault();

        if(linkLocation.indexOf('#') == -1){
            $("body").fadeOut(3000, redirectPage);
        }
    });

    function redirectPage()
    {
       window.location=linkLocation;
    }
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/5t6fenap/)

**Resources :**

[***indexOf()***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through your code its almost correct you simply need to change something in your click function because `preventDefault();` creating problem with the default functionality of `<a></a>` tag...
Also click on Allow block content when it ask you in IE.

Instead try this :-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").css("display","none");
   $("body").fadeIn(2000);
   $("a").click(function() {
      linkLocation=this.href;
      if(!linkLocation.contains("#"))
      {
          $("body").fadeOut(1000,redirectPage);
      }

});

     function redirectPage()
     {
       window.location=linkLocation;
     }
});
</script>
```

I hope this will work for you..

Comment: are you sure redirectPage() function is being called when you click on the link? Try your console.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the answer was to set the z-index. I have a stack of absolutely positioned divs and wanted to fade between them. The only way I could get IE8 to handle the fades nicely was to set the z-index of the element to be faded in higher than the element to be faded out.

```
$('#fadeoutdiv').css({zIndex:99}).fadeOut(2000);
$('#fadeindiv').css({zIndex:90}).fadeOut(2000);
```

and for redirect Check the [Link Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248251/internet-explorer-jquery-redirect)